# Load image larger than 2048x2048 into ImageView on Android

Tags: android, opengl-es, imageview

I need to load high res remote images to imageview, but without using any external libraries or frameworks. Images are like 2150x1500 px, and here is my code for loading:

```
                URL imageUrl = new URL(url);

                HttpURLConnection connection;
                if (url.startsWith("https://")) {
                    connection = (HttpURLConnection) imageUrl.openConnection();
                } else {
                    connection = (HttpURLConnection) imageUrl.openConnection();
                }
                connection.setConnectTimeout(30000);
                connection.setReadTimeout(30000);
                connection.setInstanceFollowRedirects(true);

                InputStream is = connection.getInputStream();                               
                OutputStream os = new FileOutputStream(f);
                CacheUtils.CopyStream(is, os);
                os.close();
                image = decodeFile(f);
                img.setImageBitmap(image);
```

and here is decodeFile function:

```
return BitmapFactory.decodeStream(new FileInputStream(f), null, o2);
```

and I always get texture size too big exception. Is there any way to load these images? Or is there a way to resize image not 2 or 4 times, but resize to fit 2048 pixels by width?

Answer (score 0):

```
class DownloadImage extends AsyncTask<String, Void, Bitmap> 
{
    ImageView bmImage;

    public DownloadImage(ImageView bmImage) {
        this.bmImage = bmImage;
    }
    @Override
    protected Bitmap doInBackground(String... urls) {
        String urldisplay = urls[0];
        Bitmap mIcon11 = null;
        try {
            InputStream in = new java.net.URL(urldisplay).openStream();
            mIcon11 = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(in);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            Log.e("Error", e.getMessage());
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return mIcon11;
    }
    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(Bitmap result) {
        bmImage.setImageBitmap(Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(result, 120, 120, false));
    }
}
```

Specify the height and width you need instead of 120.

Call this in your oncreate

```
new DownloadImage((ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageView1))
                .execute("https://.........");
```

Comment: I tried that, but I got Out of memory exception and app crashes (when I use 2048 height and width).

Comment: could you give me the image url?

Comment: I'm trying to use it int combination with viewpager (user should scroll between n images that are being downloaded from the internet). It works in genymotion simulator, but on device (Nexus 7) doesnt. here is my istantiateItem method from view pager adapter: http://codeviewer.org/view/code:4367